# How to make the "change event" work on a select drop-down menu when using .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the select drop-down menu below:

```
 <select id="select-param-num">
 <option value='0'>0</option>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
 </select>
```

I have the trigger bellow, to update things on my page when the user change the selected option: (I am calling that first)

```
$('#select-param-num').change(function () {    
    //update stuff
});
```

And then in my initialization I am setting the drop-down menu at a specific value like this:

```
$("select#select-param-num option[value=2]").attr('selected', true);
```

I was expecting that .change() would have been called, to automatically update my page but it doesn't.

Do you have any suggestion to make it happen?

Thanks

Comment: in your select there's no option with value = 6..

Comment: Instead of using `attr()`, you should set the select value using `.val()` as you would any other input. Whether this fires the change event I'm not sure - give it a go

Comment: I tried; .val(); but this doesn't update the drop-down menu text on my page , only the value is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trigger the event, 3 ways for that:

```
$('#select-param-num').change(); //same as .trigger('change')
$('#select-param-num').trigger('change'); //same as .change()
$('#select-param-num').triggerHandler('change'); //same as others but just because change event doesn't bubble
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to run your event handling code:

```
$("#select-param-num").triggerHandler('change');
```

You should also not use `.attr` to set the value of the dropdown. Do this instead:

```
$("#select-param-num").val("2");
```

Comment: thanks, I tried; $("#select-param-num").val("2"); but this doesn't update the drop-down menu text, only the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger for that .

```
$('#select-param-num').trigger('change');
```

[**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

In your select, there's no option with value=6. If you add it, and change a little the code, it works. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjJkN/

**code**

```
$('#select-param-num').change(function () {    
    $("select#select-param-num option[value=6]").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```